# How to access last 5 images from the list of sub folders and save it in some order of folders? Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I have a dataset containing multiple subfolders. i will give some description.

```
Main Folder(Casia)
2-Sub folders (1-NI_Acropped, 2-VL_Acropped)
    each have 3 sub folders(1.1- Dark, 1.2-Strong, 1.3-Weak)
    each have 80 sub folders(P001, P002, ... P080)
    each have 6 sub folders (ANG, DIS, FEA, HAP, SAD SUR).
```

Q1 I want to make a logic that creates the folders like this:

```
Main Folder(Casia)
2-Sub folders (1-NI_Acropped, 2-VL_Acropped)
    each have 3 sub folders(1.1- Dark, 1.2-Strong, 1.3-Weak)
and discard 80 folder and make 6-sub folder in dark strong and in weak
    like for everyone.
```

Q2 Now Can access last 5 images of every 6 folders of every 80 folders and save it to the created folders in Q1.

> See the attach pic for detail. Please Help me to create the logic
>   Note: Only the last 6 folders contain the images.

Comment: You need to be a bit more clear on what basis you want to choose the images you want to retain. Does every folder contain images? Or do you simply want to move some files and get rid of intermediate directories which serve you no purpose?

Even then it seems to me, that it has little to do with image processing. What did you try to solve your problem?

Comment: the last 6 folders contain the frames or images, i want to take the last 5 images from every folder. e.g; 80 persons in has 6 expressions Anger, Disgust and so on... it contains multiple images. i want to retrieve last 5  only. and want to get rid of 80 folders. and make 6 folders in Dark , Strong , Weak and merge those last 5's in it.